# Error while using "EpiEstim" and "ggplot2" libraries

Tags: r, ggplot2, command-line

First of all, I must say I'm completely noob in R. So I apologize in advance for asking for help with such a simple task. My task is to form a graph of COVID-19 cases for a certain period using data from the CSV file. Unfortunately, at the moment I cannot contact the person from the World Health Organization who provided the data and the script for launching. But I was left with an error that I cannot fix either myself, not with the help of Google.

**script.R**

```
library(EpiEstim)
library(ggplot2)
COVID<-read.csv("dataset.csv")
res_parametric_si<-estimate_R(COVID$I,method="parametric_si",config=make_config(list(mean_si=4,std_si=3)))
plot(res_parametric_si)
```

**dataset.csv**

```
Date,Suspected per day,Total suspected,Discarded/pending,Confirmed per day,Total confirmed,Deaths per day,Deaths Total,Case fatality rate,Daily confirmed,Recovered per day,Recovered total,Active cases,Tested with PCR,# of PCR tests total,average tests/ 7 days,Inf HCW,Inf HCW/d,Vent HCW,Susp per day
01-Jul-20,1239,91172,45285,889,45887,12,1185,2.58%,889,505,20053,24649,11109,676684,10073,6828,63,,1239
02-Jul-20,1249,92421,45658,876,46763,27,1212,2.59%,876,505,20558,24993,13167,689851,9966,6874,46,,1249
03-Jul-20,1288,93709,46032,914,47677,15,1227,2.57%,914,597,21155,25295,11825,701676,9915.7,6937,63,,1288
04-Jul-20,926,94635,46135,823,48500,22,1249,2.58%,823,221,21376,25875,9934,711610,9957,6990,53,,926
05-Jul-20,680,95315,46272,543,49043,13,1262,2.57%,543,327,21703,26078,6696,718306,9963.7,7030,40,,680
06-Jul-20,871,96186,46579,564,49607,21,1283,2.59%,564,490,22193,26131,9343,727649,10303.9,7046,16,,871
07-Jul-20,1170,97356,46942,807,50414,23,1306,2.59%,807,926,23119,25989,13568,741217,10806,7092,46,,1170
```

**Error**

> Error in process_I(incid) (script.R#4): incid must be a vector or a dataframe with either i) a column called 'I', or ii) 2 columns called 'local' and 'imported'.

Comment: First step would be to read the help on the function "estimate_R". In your case you should probably rename the columns you want to use as incidence (so either as I if you have the total number of incidences, or local and imported if you have the split between local infections and imported infections.

Comment: Well, I do that before. But renaming random column to 'local' and 'imported' doesn't change error. And renaming any column to 'I'/'ii' throws new error 'Default config will estimate R on weekly sliding windows. To change this change the t_start and t_end arguments. Error in check_times(config$t_start, config$t_end, T) (script.R#4): t_start must be a vector of integers between 2 and the number of timesteps in incid.'. Doesn't ring a bell to me. It looks like that must be handled in some other way. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: Could it be that your example just has not enough data points? "Default config will estimate R on weekly sliding windows. To change this change the t_start and t_end arguments.", See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example data the issue seems to be that it does only cover 7 data points, and the configurator assumes that there it can window over more than 7 days. What worked for me was the following code (working in the sense that it does not throw an error).

```
config <- make_config(incid = COVID$Daily.confirmed, 
                  method="parametric_si", 
                  list(mean_si=4,std_si=3, t_start = c(2,3),t_end = c(6,7)))
res_parametric_si<-estimate_R(COVID$Daily.confirmed,method="parametric_si",config=config)
plot(res_parametric_si)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, forgot to mark it as helpful. I modified the script to fit my needs based on your answer. A little clarification about an error. If the timing/date is incorrect or small, the CLI returns an error (non-zero exit), but the graph still is generated. In GUI, this is naturally not a problem.